# Change background so that site does not look like a modal dialog

Tags: feature-request, design

The current background has an opacity which makes it look like a [modal dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). This creates confusion when using the site, as it looks like a pop-up. As well, it creates the sensation that the site is only using around 60% of the screen real estate.

Comment: A modal dialog, huh? That's a new one.

Comment: Are you referring to meta or main?

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze, the background of both sites is pretty much the same, so I guess that this applies for both sites.